# How to convert price in string into value in swift iOS SDK

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode

Please guide me an issue, I am getting a price from the server as below  (as an example)

```
two hundred forty-two
```

and I want to convert this value into 242.00.

Please guide me on how to convert it.

I know we can use .spellOut with NumberFormatter for converting value into String but can't find a way to do the above.

Comment: `NumberFormatter` has a method `number(from: String)`? It doesn't work? Else, I wonder if there is a (NS)DataDetector that might work on that.

Comment: @Larme Thanks, tried but didn’t work.

Comment: ask your backend to change the text for number.

Comment: This is really a server problem. Are you sure that the server intends for your to parse this string into a real number? Perhaps it is only intended to be displayed as text to the user and not actually converted to decimal. If not, then it's really the responsibility of the server to change this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, you have managed to [nerd-snipe](https://xkcd.com/356/) me.

I've implemented a number string parser as a Swift package. I don't expect you to bring in a whole package just to do this, but you might find some inspiration here:

https://github.com/daltonclaybrook/NumberParser